# Retrieving Date value through constructor and storing it in variable of type Date

Tags: java, date

It throws exception while trying to parse String to Date after getting Date value as a string from the user. 
What should be done in order to store the Date value (or) is there any any specific method to retrieve date.

Medicine.java

```
package Medicine;
import java.util.Date;

public abstract class Medicine {

public int price;
    Date expiryDate;

    Medicine() {
    }

    Medicine(int price, Date expiryDate) {
    this.price=price;
    this.expiryDate=expiryDate;
    }

    public void getDetails() {
    System.out.println("The price is "+this.price);
    System.out.println("The expiry Date for the product is "+this.expiryDate);
    }

    abstract void displayLabel();

}
```

---

Tablet.java

```
package Medicine;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Tablet extends Medicine{

Date expDate;
void displayLabel() {
    System.out.println("Store in a cool and dry place");
}

Tablet() {
}

Tablet(int price, Date expDate) {
    this.price=price;
    this.expDate=expDate;
}
}
```

---

Execution Class

```
int price;

Date expDate=new Date();;

Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

Medicine[] medicineArray =new Medicine[5];

DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");

System.out.println("Enter Tablet's price");

price = reader.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter Tablet's expiry date in yyyy-dd-mm format");

String stringExpDate=reader.nextLine();


try {
            expDate=df.parse(stringExpDate);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Date format not parsed");
        }
        Medicine med1=new Tablet(price,expDate);
        med1.getDetails();
        med1.displayLabel();
```

Output:

Enter Tablet's price

23

Enter Tablet's expiry date in yyyy-dd-mm format

Date format not parsed

The price is 23

The expiry Date for the product is null

Comment: Do you even understand your own code?

Comment: yes @Jay. help me to improve the code if you could understand what is already given

Answer (score 1):

Your example says

> Enter Tablet's expiry date in yyyy-dd-mm format

But your format is `new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");`.

First decide which one is the format you really want, and then change the `mm` (minutes) to `MM` (months).

You also don't need to redefine `Date expDate;` in `Tablet` class, since `Medicine` already has `expiryDate` which is inherited by `Tablet`.

Comment: The output that I get is,

Enter Tablet's price

23

Enter Tablet's expiry date in yyyy-dd-mm format
Date format not parsed
The price is 23
The expiry Date for the product is null

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( "2016-01-23" )
```

## java.time

The Answer by Kayaman is correct. Your formatting codes were incorrect. Be sure to read the documentation more carefully.

Also, you are using old troublesome legacy date-classes now supplanted by the java.time classes. These include `LocalDate` for a date-only value with no time-of-day and no time zone.

Your input string format complies with ISO 8601 standard. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2016-01-23" );
```

Answer (score -1):

You had some problems in both Tablet and Medicine Classes.

Try from here:

```
    abstract public class Medicine
{
    public int price;
    public Date expiryDate;

    Medicine(int price, Date expiryDate)
    {
        this.price=price;
        this.expiryDate=expiryDate;
    }

    public void getDetails() {
        System.out.println("The price is "+this.price);
        System.out.println("The expiry Date for the product is "+this.expiryDate);
    }

    abstract void displayLabel();
}
```

and here

```
public class Tablet extends Medicine {

    Date expDate;

    void displayLabel() {
        System.out.println("Store in a cool and dry place");
    }

    public Tablet(int price, Date expDate)
    {
        super(price, expDate);
    }

}
```

the next part should be easy!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public class Tablet extends Medicine{

//Date expDate;
void displayLabel() {
    System.out.println("Store in a cool and dry place");
}

Tablet() {
}

Tablet(int price, Date expDate) {
    this.price=price;
    this.expiryDate=expDate;
}

}

int price;
        Date expDate=new Date();
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        Medicine[] medicineArray =new Medicine[5];
        DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-mm");
        System.out.println("Enter Tablet's price");
        price = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Tablet's expiry date in yyyy-dd-mm format");
        String stringExpDate=reader.next();
        try { 
            expDate=df.parse(stringExpDate);
            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        System.out.println("Date format not parsed");
        }
    Medicine med1=new Tablet(price,expDate);
    med1.getDetails();
    med1.displayLabel();
```